# Should I upload my CV to a blog I've founded with a friend or should I create a personal website for it instead?

Tags: blog, site-structure

Currently, I'm in a doubt which is related to the structure and conventions pertaining to blogs.
I've created a blog with my friend on which we write stuff about technology etc.
On that blog, we have dedicated profile pages for us.
My question is regarding this page. Should I format that page as a portfolio and upload my resume on that as well, or should I do all this on a separate personal website making the blog's profile page refer to my personal website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of this depends upon what you are expecting to achieve. You do not say in your question.

For example, are you looking for a job, freelance work, or to market yourself or expertise for other purposes, etc? Are you using the blog for this purpose?

Certainly a profile page on the blog is appropriate and adds credibility within search engines. Profiles are a factor in authority and trust that boosts your pages in search. I would be sure to add a profile page on the blog and a snippet on the bottom of your posts that links to the profile page.

Remember that blogs may be interesting, but are not generally interesting to employers. There are some exceptions of course, however, blogs are generally more casual and not what employers are searching for.

If you want more, such as a job, freelance work, or just plain ole' marketing, you may want to create a personal website specifically for that purpose. It would need to be professional and detailed. I would write articles that reflect your expertise that are concise and detailed. Do not make them the same ole' "me too" pages, but pages that are thought provoking and cover details no one else covers. Strive to cover topics thoroughly. Remember you will not be creating blog pages, but something more like white papers but more brief.

You will want to write about 30-50 high quality pages. Writing takes more time than people think, however, taking it one page at a time and working on it steadily will yield good results. Just be organized and focused.

Remember that you want to write about skills and expertise that you want to market. Do not dilute your site with too much information that dilutes the sites topic.

Do not forget to explore soft skills such as team leading, management, negotiating if they apply.

And of course you will want to link your blog profile to your personal website clearly so people can find it.

Under no circumstances do I recommend uploading a CV. It is a privacy matter and they do not seem to work as well as people like. Online CVs are not taken seriously.

Do something like a CV without creating a full CV if you feel this is necessary. You should not create any page that looks and smells like a CV. I would not add dates, job titles, etc. like on a CV. You are, in fact, creating a brag sheet just like a CV without the traditional CV look and feel. This instills the feel of confidence.

Use a contact form or a clickable "dial now" button.

If you want a CV like page, I would suggest something different.

Here is an old trick I used when consulting that may help. I created a brief CV and a full detail page for every task I took on. I offered the CV and any detail page they wanted to see. I would often fax the CV and offer any detail page they wanted. The client would ask for specific detail pages to drill down on the details that interested them the most. This was the most powerful tools I had. In fact, I got the contract each and every time using this method.

In your case, I would not create a CV "like" page at all, but detail pages for experience that reflects the skills you want to market.

You will want to create detailed pages for work that you are particularly proud of.

I hope I answered your question. If not, ping me and I will come back.